# jQuery - Unable to get confirmation dialog to appear in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to display a confirm dialog to display a custom message which will either save or ignore changes to a form depending on which button is clicked.

I have a partial code segment that I made work with Firefox that does not work anymore.
Using a confirm function within the beforeunload event handler I am  unable to show the confirm dialog in Firefox to prevent the user to change the page without either accepting changes or discarding changes.

Is my approach incorrect or is this an issue with the browser?

Thank you.

```javascript
    var confirmVal = false;
    var firstConfirm = false;

 $(window).bind('beforeunload', function ()  {
                    if (!firstConfirm) {
                        firstConfirm = true;
                        //This is where the confirm dialog should show
                        //It worked in firefox previously but not currently
                        //It still works in Internet Explorer
                        confirmVal = confirm("Save changes? \"OK\" saves changes. \"Cancel\" removes changes.");
                    }
                    if (confirmVal) {
                          // Perform update of database in this block with ajax                
                   }
                   else
                    return;

            });
```

Comment: Works fine for me using FF in jsFiddle. Are you sure you have jquery included in there? http://jsfiddle.net/sC38X/

Comment: Thank you for the link.  I had to "run" the code in jsfiddle to see the dialog.  I want to be certain that the code works when "leaving" the page.  That is my issue.  But that gives me some confidence that my code is triggering a confirm.

Comment: Ok, so I tried going to a new page other than the current one and the dialog came up.  Is there another event I need such as reload for triggering the confirm?

Comment: You are no longer able to alert/confirm from inside the beforeunload handler, so this doesn't work anymore.  This was "fixed" in [https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=588292].

Answer (score 0):

Edit/Warning : Seems my solution doesn't work in Firefox, see first comment below.

You don't need the confirm() for this. 
Simply put a string in the return in order to trigger an alert.

Exemple :

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
    var e = $.Event('webapp:page:closing');
    $(window).trigger(e); // let other modules determine whether to prevent closing
    if(e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        // e.message is optional
        return e.message || 'You have unsaved stuff. Are you sure to leave?';
    }
});
```

More informations here : http://hackab.it/2013/05/page-closing-confirm/.

Comment: This won't work in firefox.  You have no control over the message.  Check out https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=588292.